# Which executable does a core file belong to?

Tags: python, debugging, coredump

I have a python program that spawns a number of processes, one of which segfaults and dumps core.  Is there a way to find out which executable produced the resulting core file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "file" program can tell you; type "file core".